# How to I initialise an array inside the contructor in solidity?

Tags: solidity, remix, dapps, solidity-0.5.x, solidity-0.6.x

I'm using the remix IDE.I want to define the size of the array at the time constructor is called. Someone please help.
This is what I tried :

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.8.0;
contract Vote
{   
    struct Proposal
    {
        uint votecount;
    }
    Proposal[] proposal;   
            
    constructor(uint no)
    {           
        proposal=new Proposal[](no);     
    }    
}
```

Error: UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct Vote.Proposal memory[] memory to storage not yet supported.
Another :

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.8.0;
contract Vote
{               
    struct Proposal
    {
        uint votecount;
    }
    Proposal[] proposal;
                        
    constructor(uint no)
    {               
        for(uint i=0;i<no;i++)
            proposal.votecount.push(0);
    }    
}
```

Error: TypeError: Member "votecount" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct Vote.Proposal storage ref[] storage ref. proposal.votecount.push(0); ^----------------^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Proposal[] proposal` declaration in your code is of a storage array.

As such, you don't need to initialize it with `proposal = new Proposal[](...);`.

You can simply push into it as many items as you'd like.

The only thing actually missing there is an access-level (`public`/`internal`/`private`).

---

As with regards to your push attempt, simply change this:

```
proposal.votecount.push(0);
```

To this:

```
proposal.push(Proposal(0));
```

Or better yet, to this:

```
proposal.push(Proposal({votecount: 0}));
```

---

**UPDATE:**

There are generally 4 types of arrays that you should know about:

1. A static local array - declared with a constant size, inside a function
2. A dynamic local array - declared without a constant size, inside a function
3. A static global array - declared with a constant size, outside of all functions
4. A dynamic global array - declared without a constant size, outside of all functions

Types 1 and 2 reside in `memory`.

Types 3 and 4 reside in `storage`.

Type 2 is the only one which you need to allocate before attempting to use, for example:

```
function func(uint len) {
    uint[] memory arr = new uint[](len);
    ...
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by storage array? Will my code work if the array was locally defined? Why can't I simply define the size in a constructor like I would have in another programming language like Java? I'm new to solidity programming, still learning the basics.

Comment: @VasviSood: See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the concept now.

Answer (score 1):

Your array is composed of `Proposal` but you are trying to `push` a `0` into a `struct` member.

You can only push a `Proposal` on to an array of `Proposal`. Try this:

```
pragma solidity 0.7.6;

// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

contract Vote {
           
    struct Proposal {
        uint votecount;
    }
    
    Proposal[] proposals;
        
    constructor(uint no) {
        Proposal memory p;
        for(uint i=0; i<no; i++) {
            proposals.push(p);
        }
    }    
}
```

Hope it helps.